# Hibernate not getting changes from database even I turn off the session everytime and turn off the 2nd level cache

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate fetch as follows (it is called by a synchronized method in threads). The problem is if I updated the status_id to 1 in the DB console, the code won't pick it up. And when I run the sql Hibernate show_sql printed out   in the console, it can find one record. Moreover, I can see the select sql being run every time via show sql.

To make the problem clear, if I update the record status to 1 and then start the application, the code will return me one record and after processing, the record status will be updated to 2. As I expected, after that, the code will return nothing cause the status being updated to 2. However, if I manually update the status to 1, it won't pick it up.

As you can see from the configuration, I have already turn off the 2nd level cache and every time, I close the session. **I am using Enum to define the Hibernate connection. So the sessionFactory is always the same instance.** I don't know if this matters but I assume that is what it should be.

The dao code is

```
        Session session = null;
        String sql = "from MyEntity rr where status_id = 1;"
        try {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

            Query q = session.createQuery(sql);

            q.setMaxResults(1);

            List resultList = q.list();

            if (resultList.isEmpty())
                return null;

            return (MyEntity) resultList.get(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
```

The code to update the status is

```
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(myEntity);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entity doesn't exist, you need to invoke `save()` on it, otherwise you need to invoke `update()`, it will modify the existing persistent object in database.

Be aware everytime invoke save() would insert a new row in database. You may use `saveOrUpdate()` to achieve above `save()` and `update()` actions, Hiberate will either call save or update depends on the situation and take care of it.

You can invoke flush() after each saveOrUpdate() which forces Hibernate execute save or update in your database.

Comment: This is the part I get confused when I search online. I tried to fetch from DB table. why save or update get involved?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Once I put the transaction on fetch, it start to work. Don't know why. Any one can give some explaination? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with: "transaction on fetch"?

Comment: When I add session.beginTransaction() just like update, it will start to pick it up. Don't know why